# Getting wrong size of pdf file by mail

Tags: pdf, smtpclient, memorystream, mailmessage

I am sending a pdf file size 278kb but I'm getting a file size 5 kb that I can't open... I don't understand where is the problem... this is my code :

```
 MailMessage oMail = new MailMessage();
            string base64String = "";
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var bytes = client.DownloadData(pdfUrl);
                  base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
            }
            var fileName = FileName;                
            MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64String));                
            Attachment data = new Attachment(strm, fileName);           
            oMail.Attachments.Add(data); 
            oMail.From = new MailAddress(from);
            oMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(to));
            oMail.Subject = subject;
            oMail.Body = body;          
            SmtpClient oServer = new SmtpClient("XXX.XXX.XX.XXX");
            oServer.Port = **;
            oServer.EnableSsl = false;
            
                oServer.Send(oMail);
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? In particular, have you checked whether `strm` actually contains your pdf or probably some html telling you something went wrong?

Comment: @mkl I debugged it and I tasted my pdfurl and it worked fine.. dont understand why html is gone...